# Problem with markboth

Tags: sectioning, isodate, mark

I'm using `isodate` package since

1. A user should insert the date as the title of the chapter in the format as in the example : `31/12/1987`
2. The chapter should have the title `31st Dec 1987`,

following some post here I arrived at:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[orig,british]{isodate}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\def\short@month@english{\ifcase\month\or
    Jan\or Feb\or Mar\or Apr\or May\or Jun\or
    Jul\or Aug\or Sep\or Oct\or Nov\or Dec\fi}
\newcommand{\printshortdate}[1]{{%
  \let\month@english\short@month@english% Update English month lookup (locally)
  \printdate{#1}}}% Call traditional \printdate
\newcommand{\printsupdate}[1]{{
 \let\day@english\supday@english
 \printdate{#1}
}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\chaplab}[1]{\label{chap:#1}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{\printshortdate{31/12/1987}}
 \blindtext
 \blindtext
 \blindtext
 \blindtext
 \blindtext
 \blindtext
\end{document}
```

However there is something wrong with `\markboth` since, if I remove `\blindtext` command and so the document is just one page, all is ok, while adding text, I get errors and the chapter name in the header is a mess. I would like to have as the header exactly `31st Dec 1987`

### Note Added

I'm using `isodate` since in the same document I need the same date but in other format and, as a user I want to insert it only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command has to be robust in order to go to mobile arguments.

The trick is replacing `newcommand` with `DeclareRobustCommand`

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[orig,british]{isodate}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\short@month@english{\ifcase\month\or
    Jan\or Feb\or Mar\or Apr\or May\or Jun\or
    Jul\or Aug\or Sep\or Oct\or Nov\or Dec\fi}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\printshortdate}[1]{%
  \let\month@english\short@month@english% Update English month lookup (locally)
  \printdate{#1}%
  }% Call traditional \printdate

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter{\printshortdate{31/12/1987}}
 \lipsum[4-12]
\end{document}
```

With output (on page 2):

[image]

Please mind the fact that I deleted some extra `{`s (in the `newcommand` definition)

Answer (score 0):

If you need it only for one chapter use

```
\chapter*{\printshortdate{31/12/1987}}
```

if it shouldn't appear in the TOC, or

```
\chapter{\protect\printshortdate{31/12/1987}}
```

which is, of course,  the same the solution of the other answer.